# Javascript button to toggle multiple css animations

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a  series of containers with a flip animation that activates on hover. I would like for them to not only activate on hover, but also on a javascript button click that would use a single button to toggle flip all.

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="front">
                    <a href="link1.html">
                        <img src="images/frontimg1.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <div class="fliplinks">
                        <a href="link1.html">
                            <p>text1</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

These are repeated for as many objects as I use and rely on the following CSS:

```
.flip-container {
    float:left;
    margin: 7.5px;
}
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

**Edit:** A jsfiddle as requested: https://jsfiddle.net/futbyyef/

Comment: If you provide a jsfiddle it'd be easier to refactor it to achieve what you want. You should make a class also trigger the same effect than the hover; and with javascript you can toggle that class on all the elements (at once or with a certain delay depending on the effect you're after).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that they all have the `.flip-container` class,  you could add a function like this.

```
<script>
    $('.toggle-button').click(function(){
        $('.flip-container').toggleClass('hover');
    }
</script>
```

Then you just need to include a button to toggle it.  Something like

```
<button class="toggle-button">Test Button</button>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pevbckru/1) that works.  Make sure to include jQuery on your page.

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, I will attempt to implement it this evening. Are you saying I need to add the jQuery to my header, or just the js script tags in the page?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean something like your

<button class="test-button">
Test
</button>

Sounds good to me. Thanks!

Comment: The button can go anywhere on the page.  I'm talking about including the jQuery library.  http://jquery.com/

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but it doesn;t appear to be working in my page, this is the library I loaded: <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: That is the right library.  Do you have a link to your page I could look at?

Comment: I don't, but I think I'm still placing one of the scripts wrong. Do you think you could show a markdown of what the html page should look like?
Edit: nevermind, I'm a fool and was entering in the script wrong. Thanks so much for the help!